# Why adding a new set to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ makes an open set?

Tags: real-analysis

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, suppose $A$ is an open set and $B$ is any set. Show that the set

$$
A+B:=\{a+b:\,\,a \in A,\,b \in B\}
$$
is open.

To prove consider $B$ can be any set, even a point $\{b\}$, how can we have a ball containing $A$ and $\{b\}$? If we can define it, we are done but I do not know how?

Answer (score 4):

Observe that
$$A+B = \bigcup_{b\in B} A+\{b\}$$

If you show that $A+\{b\}$ is open then $A+B$ is a union of open sets which is open.

So why $A+\{b\}$ is open? You don't have to show that it contains an open ball, instead look at the map $f(x) = x-b$ the pre-image of $A$ is $f^{-1}(A)=A+\{b\}$. Since $f$ is continuous and $A$ is open we have that $A+\{b\}$ is open.

Comment: Can you explain the first line? I mean, what does that union mean?

Comment: Why not just say $x\to x+b$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @Saeed The first line is just an equality of sets. Let $x\in A+B$ then there exists $a,b$ such that $x=a+b$ and so $a+b \in \bigcup_{b'\in B} A+\{b'\}$. The other direction is even easier. If $x\in\bigcup_{b\in B} A+\{b\}$ then there exists $b\in B$ such that $x\in A+\{b\}$ and so there exists $a\in A$ such that $x=a+b$.

Comment: @Saeed If you ask why an union of open sets is open, then you can find a proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453487/the-union-of-two-open-sets-is-open-in-metric-spaces

Comment: @Yanko I understand that, what I do not understand is why you take the union of $A$ over elements of $B$. Also, I cannot understand why the left results in the right hand side?

Comment: @Saeed I explained that in my first comment, didn't I? I'm not sure I understand your question.